# Does karate support -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount for re run failed tests in Jenkins

Tags: maven, testing, jenkins-pipeline, karate

I am using karate framework for my automated testing project and I am currently using the cucumber report as well.

Now I'm facing an issue with re-run only the failed tests in Jenkins

tried it with -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount but it doesn't work. Is there any specific config to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not directly supported. You could generate the list of tests to re-run by looking at the `Results` class / data.

Comment: Do you have any plans to provide this support anytime soon. This would be a great addition to the framework

Comment: yes, but if you contribute code it can happen faster

Comment: @PeterThomas is rerun functionality available in the v1.X?

Comment: @Adam read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#retry-framework-experimental - if that doesn't help, consider this as not available